# why is method within React Component function constructor evaluating after the components have been initialized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components, algolia

Sorry if the title is hard to understand, because it's definitely a weird problem.

I think this screenshot best explains what's going on, and it makes no sense to me in every sense of programming. Regardless of whether a PL is interpreted or compiled, I would expect two lines within the same function to evaluate in consecutive order.

Not in this case, however:

[image]

You can clearly see in this side-by-side screenshot that the line I would have expected to print **after** the first line (consecutively speaking) actually printed/evaluated first.

This is a problem for me because the entire reason I am calling the [`index.getObject`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/get-objects/) method within the React component constructor is to use the response in the object itself. So now all the React components are just using `destName = null`.

**Can anyone explain this behavior? (bonus points if there's a way to make sure the first line evaluates first)**

additional picture to explain behavior:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the Hot Module Replacement (HMR) interrupting the normal execution of the JavaScript?

Comment: Also, your logged values for `null` might be because your `redirectId` isn't a valid value on the first renders of your `NewButton` component.

Comment: I dont get why/how the button component could possibly be rendered without the affiliated constructor that specifies the `redirectId` @RobertCooper

Comment: What happens when you log out the value of `redirectId` just before your call to `index.getObject...`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: updated the question with a picture @RobertCooper, but the redir ID's dont seem to be null

Comment: Yes, as @RandyCasburn has eluded to, this is likely caused by the `index.getObject` call being asynchronous. That means the code continues to execute even though the result of `index.getObject` hasn't been returned.

Comment: Great thanks, @RandyCasburn or cooper I am happy to credit one of you with figuring it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RandyCasburn has alluded to, this appears to be an issue with your `index.getObject` method being an asynchronous JavaScript call. This means that when calling `index.getObject`, the JavaScript continuous to execute code while it is waiting on the result of the `index.getObject` call.

Here's the canonical answer for asynchronous JavaScript questions on Stack Overflow: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)